# Jenkins-Maven continuous integration build error (need it immediatly)

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I tried building a Maven project using Jenkins and the build is successful but it throws an error saying the following, it is taking the wrong file on the `java.io.FileNotFoundException`.

Thank you.

```
    [JENKINS] Recording test results
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 3.929 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2016-06-22T16:31:49-05:00
    [INFO] Final Memory: 14M/211M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [JENKINS] Archiving     /Users/saiprasanthrajavarapu/Documents/devops/Samplejava/SampleExample/pom.xml to org.javacodegeeks/Sample1/4.0.2-SNAPSHOT/Sample1-4.0.2-SNAPSHOT.pom
/Users/saiprasanthrajavarapu/Documents/devops/Samplejava/SampleExample/pom.xml is not inside /Users/saiprasanthrajavarapu/.jenkins/workspace/maven2/Users/saiprasanthrajavarapu/Documents/devops/Samplejava/SampleExample/; will archive in a separate pass
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/saiprasanthrajavarapu/.jenkins/workspace/maven2/Users/saiprasanthrajavarapu/Documents/devops/Samplejava/SampleExample/pom.xml (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at hudson.FilePath.read(FilePath.java:1779)
    at jenkins.plugins.maveninfo.extractor.properties.PomPropertiesFinder.findProperties(PomPropertiesFinder.java:50)
    at jenkins.plugins.maveninfo.extractor.MavenInfoExtractor.extract(MavenInfoExtractor.java:58)
    at jenkins.plugins.maveninfo.extractor.MavenInfoEnvironment.tearDown(MavenInfoEnvironment.java:42)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:882)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1720)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:531)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
channel stopped
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `${JENKINS_HOME}` apparently is:

```
/Users/saiprasanthrajavarapu/.jenkins/
```

Then your *Workspace Root Directory* is:

```
/Users/saiprasanthrajavarapu/.jenkins/workspace/${ITEM_FULLNAME}
```

Your project's name apparently is *maven2* so the job's workspace is:

```
/Users/saiprasanthrajavarapu/.jenkins/workspace/maven2
```

Your *Build* → *Root POM* is defined as:

```
/Users/saiprasanthrajavarapu/Documents/devops/Samplejava/SampleExample/pom.xml
```

which will be added to the immediate above:

```
/Users/saiprasanthrajavarapu/.jenkins/workspace/maven2/Users/saiprasanthrajavarapu/Documents/devops/Samplejava/SampleExample/pom.xml
```

since the *Build* → *Root POM* is meant to be *relative* to the job's workspace. So, if you want to use a POM outside the job's workspace you have to use a *relative path* to it.

In your case:

```
../../../Documents/devops/Samplejava/SampleExample/pom.xml
↑  ↑  ↑
│  │  └─ /workspace
│  └──── /.jenkins
└─────── /saiprasanthrajavarapu
```