# Unable to configure Maven in Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

Maven version 3.3.3 (Maven is configured in my system. I'm able to get version number by `mvn -version`.)

Following is my Maven project in Jenkins:

[image]

Which basically asks me to configure Maven.

Below are the only fields available when I select *Configure System*. Though I gave the path of Maven, the error is not removed and unable to build.

[image]

Can someone help on this.

Comment: remoce the bin Folder from MAVEN_HOME, also for JAVA_HOME

Comment: Your _Build_ → _Root POM_ path probably is not going to work, as well. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38127827/1744774) for an explanation why.

Comment: @Jens, i removed the bin directory and saved the changes. Then restarted Jenkins and see the same error message.

Comment: @Uday, can you supply the new values screenshot after you removed ```bin/``` ?

Comment: Which Version of Jenkins do you use?

Answer (score 2):

Please check "Jenkins => Configuration => Global Tool Configuration". There you can define your maven-installation not only the the environment-variable MAVEN_HOME.

Afterwards you should be able to select your maven-installation in your project-build.

Answer (score 1):

ln `-s /opt/apache-maven-3.5.4/bin/mvn /usr/bin/mvn`

run `echo $PATH` in pipeline script and see paths available to Jenkins user. Once linking with maven bin path, maven started working. To check, run `mvn -v` in the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

First you should configure a JDK and *NOT* an JRE. Furthermore the `rootPOM` location is relative to the Jenkins Job Workspace which means usually only `pom.xml` nothing more...

Comment: In Jenkins global configurations, for JAVA_HOME i have configure JDK it self and not JRE.

Comment: The screen shot says something different. And of course from MAVEN_HOME  remove `bin` part.